# would i have to declare the variables all in the beginning of the code in order for it to output properly?

Tags: java

```
public class Assignment1{
    /* This piece of the code will print out a triangle 
       orientated to the left and will increase by one
       asterik every time there is a new line */

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // declaring the integer variables x and y 
        int x,y;                   

        // if 1 is greater than or equal to 11, runt he for loop and add 1.
        for(x=1; x<=11; x++){

            // if x is greater than y print add 1 and print out the next lines
            for(y=1; y<x; y++){

                // prints out the actual * in the code.
                System.out.print("*");  
            }        
            System.out.println();   
        }

        // number of spaces
        int i, j, k=2*n-2;

        // outer loop to handle number of rows
        // n in this case
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){

            // inner loop to handle number spaces
            // values changing acc. to requirement
            for(j=0; j<k; j++){
                // printing spaces
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            // decrementing k after each loop
            k = k - 2;

            // inner loop to handle number of columns
            // values changing acc. to outer loop
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++){

                // printing stars
                System.out.print("* ");
            }

            // ending line after each row
            System.out.println();
        }
        int n = 5;
        printStars(n);
    }
}
```

So I am only getting the the first part of the code in the output, I was wondering what i was doing wrong and why the second half of the code does not output, fairly new to java programming. I have been trying multiple ways but cant seem to get it, If anyone could possibily guide me. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: should i create another public class and call it from my main?

Comment: Your code is incomplete: you call `printStars()`, but there is no such function.  Please provide the rest.

Comment: And then explain what you saw when trying to step through your code in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that you put in curly braces where you don't need them. You only need to put in curly braces around code used in functions, loops, and if statements. It would be a good idea to use a program like eclipse to keep track of your curly braces, plus it will warn you of other errors

Secondly you have to declare the variable n before you use it, along with the method printStars()

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the `n` variable before you use it at `k=2*n-2;`